# Google map custom directions to Android navigation

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-maps, cordova

I am using a script modeled from google draggable map at http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-directions/draggable-directions.html to create custom driving directions on an android device.

So far just like the example I can drag the driving line on the map and reroute the directions causing the trip calculation and turn by turn directions to change.

I have seen documentation on an anchor link that will open map options on the device asking to choose a map app from a list of installed apps that interact with a map.

I would like to send the new turn by turn driving directions to the navigation and have the new route followed.

Any ideas a script or how to parse a link to open the map and/or nav would be interested and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start this is how you open up that maps app dialog that you mentioned. This is when you have one address.

```
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse("address here");
Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
startActivity(mapCall);
```